# Drive activity indicator

Tags: hard-drive, monitoring

There used to be a cool utility called OOLED which used to display the activity occurring on different drives/drive partitions. Anyone know where I can find it or any other software which does the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found [O&O DriveLED](http://www.oo-software.com/home/en/download/archive/), which is simple and available for free:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Great find. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: No longer free it seems...

Answer (score 3):

**[TrayStatus](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/09/11/traystatus-displays-indicator-of-num-lock-caps-lock-scroll-lock-status-and-hard-drive-readwrite-activity/)** Displays Indicator of Num Lock, Caps Lock, Scroll Lock Status and **Hard Drive Read/Write Activity**

[image]

**[Hard Disk Indicator](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Hard-Disk-Indicator.shtml)** - Add your hard disk LED at your system tray

choose between 5 LED colours, monitor up to 5 partitions at the same time.

*both programs are freeware.*

Comment: +1. I liked the nice touch of allowing to set a minimum bp/s threshold for disk activity.

Comment: Be aware, does not work when performance counters are disabled. Program will loop into error message.

Answer (score 3):

[DiskMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896646.aspx), which is part of the Sysinternals suite (semi-official Microsoft software), is quite a nice tool.

> DiskMon is an application that logs
>   and displays all hard disk activity on
>   a Windows system. You can also
>   minimize DiskMon to your system tray
>   where it acts as a disk light,
>   presenting a green icon when there is
>   disk-read activity and a red icon when
>   there is disk-write activity.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

See [DriveGLEAM](http://www.dirtcellar.net/software.php):

> DriveGLEAM is a fabulous hard drive
>   utility which shows read-write
>   activity for your hard drives in the
>   system notification area (tray). It
>   also supports output via parallel port
>   so that you can for example have a red
>   led for write and a green led for read
>   access. Features: Monitor physical
>   disks or partitions (or both), Allows
>   for CPU, RAM, VRAM usage display in
>   tray. Read / Write / ReadWrite and
>   Idle status indicators, Indicators in
>   tray or the parallel port, output
>   directly to LED's, Just place some
>   LED's on top of your monitor and enjoy
>   real monitoring of read/write status
>   realtime ;) (no special hardware
>   required), Uses very few resources
>   (cpu usage). Does not "hook" into your
>   system. Failure in DriveGLEAM can't
>   "freeze" your drives. Configurable
>   start with os delay. Configurable poll
>   rate.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try [gkrellm](http://gkrellm.srcbox.net/), which supports this feature and many more.

Answer (score 1):

I’d like to recommend Moo0 System Monitor. Besides other things this program monitors various HDD stats too.

This program allows user to customize the look of the interface freely.

I moved the main stats window on my taskbar. Here’s how it looks:

http://imageshack.us/a/img822/6983/fgqn.png

You can enable auto hide function, so when you move a cursor over the stats meter it disappears and reveals the taskbar. When you remove the cursor from the taskbar area, the stats meter is showed again.

Moo0 System Monitor is highly configurable, but it takes a little time to understand how to customize the program for your needs at first.

I think it’s worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

**[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)** from Sysinternals.

[image]

Comment: You had completely misunderstood the question.