# Windows Media Player doesn't notice when I change CD

Tags: windows, windows-media-player

I'm using WMP on Windows 7 Ultimate x64. When I put a CD in the drive, WMP starts itself up and I've got it set to rip the CD. This works fine.

When it's finished ripping, I eject the CD and put a new one in. The problem is that WMP doesn't notice this - it just sits there thinking it's still got the previous CD. I can play the new CD, but WMP will tell me that it's playing the songs from the old CD.

I can work around the problem by closing WMP and then either ejecting and re-inserting the CD or going to My Computer and double clicking on the CD drive icon to force it to Autoplay.

There's no Refresh button in WMP to make it check what's actually in the drive. What can I do?

Comment: how do you eject the media? in the Play tab is a software eject, it should help notify the system.

Comment: Either using that Eject option or setting the Auto-Eject checkbox - the CD gets ejected, but even though WMP has ejected it itself, it doesn't notice.

Comment: Auto Insert Notification .  http://superuser.com/questions/339543/how-to-disable-auto-insert-notification-in-windows-7 reverse everything this questioner does to try and stop the constant polling

Answer (score 0):

This has always been a bug in Windows Media Player. W10 and WMP Version 12.0.18326.207. It will not recognize when a CD is changed.  Workaround is close and reopen WMP.  ;-[