# Is it possible to avoid any periodic HDD-writes on a Windows 7 System?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

Because I am using a SSD-Harddrive as my System-Disk, I would like to minimize the amount of periodic disk-writes, while Windows is in an idle state.

Is it possible to boot up a cleansed Windows7, which would not excecute any write operations once it is in an idle state? Or will there be some internal process, which has to write something regulary or every now and then?

I tried to kill any unessentail process, using the SysinternalsSuite from MS, but after killing nearly any running process/service, the leftover system still made periodic writes to my SSD-Drive - and only to it.

This bothers me quite much, because I might invest in a small mSATA-Drive, instead of quickly wearing out my Vertex4.

I am of course aware, that it might be a solution to just use the standby mode, when in idle state, but this is just a cheap workaround and not a good solution for me.

---

Edit:

Because this started to bug me really bad, I finally reinstalled Win7 x64, and to my suprise, although there is no network connection and nearly no processes running, after a basic install I have quite some noise on ProcessMonitor and still more HDD-activity, than I would like to have.

Durability aside, I would really like to know, how idle the most idle could be for a fresh Win7 x64 installation. So what is the most reduced running setup for Win7?

I already deactivated pagefile and hybernation, just in case. And am working on a list of running services and processes.

Comment: 1) How would you boot up a cleaned windows 7 without reinstalling that every time? (And that with a lot of writes to do so)  2) Why worry about writes? First generation SSDs had limited writes, but modern ones will do fine; even if you put them under heavy write load for years. By the time you have to worry about it they will be old and outdated and you probably have already bought a new computer.

Comment: 1) process controll - once I have a clean baseline, which I know to utilize only the bare minimum, I can control what I want to add. This would not require to reinstall. 2) Hm, I'll look into that, but none the less - it is irritating to have the hdd-led flashing like every second, and I don't recall this to be usuall. It's uneccessary wear&tear - I don't like it :)

Comment: There's really no need whatsoever to go to these kinds of lengths. You have a high-endurance ([NDurance 2.0](http://www.ocztechnology.com/aboutocz/press/2012/491) / Everest) SSD. These kinds of background writes won't wear out the drive even in decades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well despite the "don't worry" about it responses here and on the net in general, I just could not let go of this (anyone else with a bit of OCD might relate) and found at least some answears and improvement.

Besides the very accurate accepted answer here:

[Why does my hard drive LED light blink every second?](https://superuser.com/q/229546/160170)

Which makes Windows and CDRom/DVD-Devices the bad guys. However in my case (SATA-Drives) it was not enough to disable autorun, I have to disable the drives in order to reduce the blinking to an absolute minimum.

I also found this nice piece of information, which was also causing LED-Blinks and actual HDD-Writes:

Apparently Windows is writing some fille to determine a reliability measure, which was mainly intendet for servers but is also active for a workstation installation.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Reliability
```

is the registry path, where one needs to set `TimeStampInterval` to `0`

Here is my source: http://www.sevenforums.com/crashes-debugging/50621-why-does-my-hard-drive-activity-light-constantly-blink-6.html

Further, any services, like the SearchIndexer or DriveCache might cause extra activities.